# Install ODBC and Sybase on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: apache2, php, php7, odbc, mssql

I am currently building Ubuntu 16.04 server for our project. Error occurs when I'm trying to install:

`sudo apt-get install php5-odbc php5-sybase tdsodbc`

The error says:

`Unable to locate package php5-odbc
Unable to locate package php5-sybase`

I successfully installed it on my previous server which is Ubuntu 14.04.
My question is, how can I install it to my latest server which is Ubuntu 16.04?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those packages are available in Ubuntu 16.04 in php7.

Run this:

```
$ sudo apt install php7.0-odbc php7.0-sybase tdsodbc
```

While I wouldn't advise it unless you really need it.  You can install php5 on `16.04` with:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install php5.6
```

That should also add the available `php5` modules.

Comment: I successfully install after I run your first code above, but when I try to run my project, and still `could not find driver`. Do you have any ideas what to do next? Thanks

Comment: Please disregard my question above, I already fix my problem to that.
Thanks for your answer. My system is now working. Cheers.

Comment: YOu're welcome... glad your problem i s resolved.

Comment: For nowadays (2020) and *php7.4-fpm*, there are no `sudo apt install php7.4-odbc`, need to install **7.2**... It is ok, or can be a big mess?